# Elegant way to return first non-Missing column in Dataset

Tags: dataset, filtering, date-and-time

I have a `Dataset[]` with some data and a TON of columns. Each row contains several columns for dates, which contain `DateObject` values, but they aren't always populated. If a value is Null, I've replaced it with `Missing[]` for a) prettier display in Dataset visualization, b) to allow use of `MissingQ` and `DeleteMissing`.

Here's my question. I am trying to get a single definitive date for each row based on the first non-Missing value. It's possible that ALL values will be missing. In that case either nothing needs to be returned or a `Missing["No date"]` is fine.

What I have so far is very ugly and crude, and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this, that simply escapes me for now?

```
Flatten[
  Take[ DeleteMissing@#, UpTo[1] ]& /@
  Normal@Values@encounters[ All,
    {"ArriveDTS", "EstimatedArriveDTS", "RegistrationDTS", 
     "TriageDTS", "InpatientAdmitDTS", "AssignToLocationDTS", 
     "DischargeDTS", "DepartDTS", "EstimatedDepartDTS", 
     "PreRegistrationDTS"}
  ]
]
```

Comment: `SelectFirst[Not @* MissingQ]`?

Comment: @Pillsy Please add as an answer. That worked wonders! Thank you!
Finished product: `encounters[All, SelectFirst[Not@*MissingQ]@*KeyTake[{"ArriveDTS", "EstimatedArriveDTS", "RegistrationDTS", "TriageDTS", "InpatientAdmitDTS", "AssignToLocationDTS", "DischargeDTS", "DepartDTS", "EstimatedDepartDTS", "PreRegistrationDTS"}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SelectFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectFirst.html) function does exactly what you want. As you note in your comment ( :) ), this will work:

```
encounters[All, SelectFirst[Not@*MissingQ]@*KeyTake[{"ArriveDTS",  
  "EstimatedArriveDTS", "RegistrationDTS", "TriageDTS", "InpatientAdmitDTS",   
  "AssignToLocationDTS", "DischargeDTS", "DepartDTS", "EstimatedDepartDTS", 
  "PreRegistrationDTS"}]]
```